# windows phone light theme making textboxes invisible

Tags: windows-phone-7, themes

I want to app background to black only so i put black background image to all the pages grids..

now the problem is when phone is running on dark theme everything is perfect but if it is running on light theme then all the things (most of them) are invisible now because when there is light theme phone changes the colors  to go dark & because of black background its invisible

```
so I set the manual colors to all the things which makes most of the things visible now but still when i click on textbox it gets dark
```

is there any solution where i can keep my black background & still have everything visible in light theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jeff Wilcox [theme manager](https://github.com/jeffwilcox/wp-thememanager) or otherwise you will need to edit the Style of all the control yourself to force the Dark theme colors.
If you want to edit all the Style manually, you can retrieve all the Black them colors from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Design\DarkBlue\ThemeResources.xaml and add them to your project App.xaml.

Comment: what do you mean by "ok to use"?

Comment: i mean overriding means tampering with phone's settings... so microsoft allows it? although they show message when we change to light theme that it will consume more battery so i guess there wont be any problem

Comment: yes it's not a problem to always show your app in Dark or Light theme. There is a lot of app which do that for branding reason.

Comment: hey but one thing when app starts and first time applicationbar opens or shows on screen there is a white flash around it is there anything to do about it?

Comment: I think probably not, I think it's because the app bar is unmanaged so it's behaving a little different than normal component and that's probably what creating the flash.

Comment: Maybe one thing you could try is set the colors on the application bar and see if that help